# DispatcherServlet and ContextLoaderListener in Spring

Tags: spring, configuration

What is the difference between `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` in Spring framework? Do we need to configure both of them in **web.xml** when we are using spring framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root WebApplicationContext is a Spring Application Context shared across the application.

> A DispatcherServlet instance actually has its own
>   WebApplicationContext.

One can have multiple DispatcherServlet instances in an application, and each will have its own WebApplicationContext.

> The root WebApplicationContext is shared across
>   the application, so if you have a root WebApplicationContext and
>   multiple DispatcherServlets, the DispatcherServlets will share the
>   root WebApplicationContext.

However, for a simple Spring MVC application, one can even have a situation where *there is no need to have a root WebApplicationContext*. A DispatcherServlet would still have its own WebApplicationContext, but it doesn’t actually need to have a parent root WebApplicationContext.

So, which beans should go in the root Web Application Context and which beans should go in the DispatcherServlet’s Web Application Context? 
Well, general beans such as services and DAOs make their way in root Web Application Context, and more web-specific beans such as controllers are included in DispatcherServlet’s Web Application Context.

Answer (score 20):

AFAIK each `DispatcherServlet` will have a `WebApplicationContext`. By default the `DispatcherServlet` looks for a spring configuration file named `[appname]-servlet.xml` under `WEB-INF` folder.

> Do we need to configure `DispatcherServlet`?

Yes, every spring application should configure `DispatcherServlet` as it is the one through which all the requests are routed. It decides the appropriate method of the controller class to handle the request. Once controller returns the `model` along with the logical view, `DispatcherServlet` takes the help of `ViewResolver` to resolve the `view` (generally JSPs) and will pass the `model` data to the view, which is finally rendered on the browser.

> Do we need to configure `ContextLoaderListener`?

No, this is not mandatory. Spring applications can live with out `ContextLoaderListener`.

> Why do we need `ContextLoaderListener`?

Usually when we build multi-tier applications we don't want to clutter all the beans in one config file `[appname]-servlet.xml`. For example if you configure `spring security` you wanted to include all those beans in `security-context.xml`, in the same way all the beans belonging to service layer are configured in `applicationContext.xml` and some would like to configure beans belonging to DAO layer in `dao-context.xml`. So when you configure all these beans in different context files, you need to let know spring that these files exist as spring only knows about `[appname]-servlet.xml`. `ContextLoaderListener` will help spring recognize all the other context files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You made it really clear. Thanks!

Comment: I could not apprehend the accepted answer that well. The simplicity of this answer makes it is crystal clear as to what is the motive behind having ContextLoaderListener and how DispatcherServlet has its role to play. Great explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When DispatcherServlet starts up, it creates a Spring application context and starts
loading it with beans declared in the configuration files or classes that it’s given.
But in Spring web applications, there’s often another application context. This
other application context is created by ContextLoaderListener

Whereas DispatcherServlet is expected to load beans containing web components
such as controllers, view resolvers, and handler mappings, ContextLoaderListener is
expected to load the other beans in your application. These beans are typically the
middle-tier and data-tier components that drive the back end of the application.

Good luck!